# ios PushNotfication not working after adding the App entitlements

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have an app in development in which the push notification are working using the development provision profile in xcode8.1. Upon uploading the app store i got a mail to add the app entitlements for push notifications.

I did so [image] .

But Now the concern is that i am not getting Notification after enabling the app entitlements. But if i turn to off then i am able to receive the notification again

I am afraid that if i submitted the build and it approved for sale then the Notification will not work on production..

How this can be fixed and cross checked ...

Also entitlement showing development and production values for in entitlements for the respective builds

Comment: Have you tried redownloading your `app store distribution profile`?

Comment: Nope,as last i downloaded the same four months back,gonna redownload the same and i'll check if that makes any difference

Comment: I haven't experience this yet, but all i can suggest is to reupdate all your profiles(provisioning) also the .pem file in your server.